# Try/Except in Python does not run correctly

Tags: python, mongodb, exception, pymongo

I am developing next code to implement pymongo. I want to catch every error, for example, during connection with DB. However, if I write a random IP (which does not exists), try/cath does not runs correctly. 'OK' is printed despite the fact that the IP does not exists.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import errors

class Mongo:

def __init__(self):    

    db = 'random ip'
    port = 27017
    mps = 50
    user = 'admin'
    pw = 'pw'
    to=100

    print('Creating MongoClient ......')
    print 'Establishing connection with MongoDB ...... ',

    try:    
        self.client = MongoClient(db, port, maxPoolSize=mps,
                                  username=user, password=pw,
                                  connectTimeoutMS=to)
        print 'OK'
    except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
        print 'ERROR'
        logging.error("Connection problem: %s", e)

# Search checks in MongoDB
def search(self):
        collections = ['new', 'old']
        try:
            for data_type in collections:
                db = self.client.get_database('db')
                collection = db[data_type + '_data']
                print 'Opening ' + data_type + '_data DB ...... ',
                cursor = collection.find({})
                print 'OK'
                writeTempData(cursor, data_type)

        except Exception as e:
            print 'ERROR'
            logging.error("Unable find data in DB: %s", e) 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Get json from MongoDB
    mongo = Mongo()
    mongo.search()
```

Output:

```
root@pc:/etc/checkPlantillas# python getPlantillas.py 
Creating MongoClient...
Establishing connection with MongoDB ...... OK
Opening new_data DB ......  OK
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks beforehand, mike.

Comment: "not working correctly" that's really not helpful. is there an error? post error & traceback if any

Comment: And is it supposed to be an exception according to the documentation?

Comment: edited. Yes, https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html?highlight=error#module-pymongo.errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note:** Starting with version 3.0 the `MongoClient` constructor no longer blocks while connecting to the server or servers, and it no
>   longer raises `ConnectionFailure` if they are unavailable, nor
>   `ConfigurationError` if the user’s credentials are wrong. Instead, the
>   constructor returns immediately and launches the connection process on
>   background threads. You can check if the server is available like
>   this:
>
> ```
> from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
> client = MongoClient()
> try:
>     # The ismaster command is cheap and does not require auth.
>     client.admin.command('ismaster')
> except ConnectionFailure:
>     print("Server not available")
> ```
>
> https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient

The client produces errors on the first actual operation, not when instantiating `MongoClient`.